# How does one add data to a Chart in an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I am trying to add data obtained from an ajax call to a chart using Chart.js.

The following code is not working:

```
$(document)
        .ready(function () {

            fetchBeds($("#site").val());

            var ctx = $('#paretoChart');
            var paretoChart = new Chart(ctx);

            fetchChartData(1, '2016-10-28', '2016-11-2', paretoChart);
        });


function fetchChartData(bed, start, end, chart) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/reports/fetchChartData",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            bed: bed,
            start: start,
            end: end

        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            var chartData = {
                labels: response.data.labels,
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Pareto of Events',
                        data: response.data.chartData,
                }]
            };

            chart.data = chartData;
            console.log(chart);
            chart.update();
        }
    });
}
```

When run, it doesn't generate any errors (my ajax call is working fine, verified in firefox). Simply nothing happens. I have a feeling it has to do with how I am applying the `data` to the chart. If I take the example data from the chart.js website and use that directly in the `new Chart(...)` call, it works fine.

Is it even possible to apply new data after the chart has been created?

Here is the data returned from the ajax call, just in case:

```
{"result":true,"message":null,"data":{"labels":["Plant","Process"],"chartData":["1","1"]}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you manually put your data does it work ?

Comment: Yes, you can apply new data after the chart has been created: [Codepen add adjust data](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/gwdYzr?editors=0010), The problem I think is in how you are instantiating your chart without data (even if it is  an empty object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I got the newest ChartJS and tried it out with your scenario.

My html:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Creating the chart:

```
$(function () {
    var ctx = $("#myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'bar', data: { labels: [], datasets: [] } });

     UpdateChart(myChart)
});
```

I had to specify the type and a data object with empty labels and datasets for it to even render on the screen as an empty chart.

My function that updates the chart:

```
function UpdateChart(chart) {
            var data =  {
                        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: '# of Votes',
                            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
            }
            chart.data.labels = data.labels
            chart.data.datasets = data.datasets
            chart.update()
        }
```

I tried doing chart.data = data but that didn't work for me. I had to specifically update data.labels then data.datasets before updating.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution but I feel better knowing I'm not alone. As far as the CTX goes, the chart.js documentation does it my way... I've used it before though, a long time ago and I remember doing it your way. Must have been an update...

Comment: If nobody comes up with a better solution I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: It has been awhile since I used it so it could very well be an update. Maybe I should look at refactoring my old chart code! I do hope someone is able to provide a more elegant solution.

Comment: I updated my answer using the newest ChartJS, please check to see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect and a lot cleaner looking.

Comment: You are welcome! And thank you, because now I can clean up my code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Worked fine by me, see my exact code below.

You have to make sure that you are using the updated .js file of the chart.js plugin. Of course, you have to include Jquery plugin on top of your every javascript file.

For this replication, I used the cdn provided by jquery and chart.js.

```
<canvas id="chart" height="400px" width="400px"></canvas>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.js">    </script>
<script>

$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8081/chart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
            var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels: response.data.labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Number of Active Customers',
                        data: response.data.chartData,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                }
            });
        }
});
</script>
```

`chart.php` file contains only the response JSON code as you may see below.

```
{
   "result":true,
   "message":null,
   "data":{
      "labels":[
         "Plant",
         "Process"
      ],
      "chartData":[
         "10",
         "1"
      ]
   }
}
```